# DataEncoding and compression in HDF5 format

Tags: export, bugs, data-format, compression, hdf5-format

I would like to export data in HDF5 format with Mathematica 9.
The Mathematica manual about Import and Export of this format can be read [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HDF5.html).

As I'm dealing with large arrays, export often lead to 100MB+ files.
I'd like to use the HDF5 `"DataEncoding"` to compress the exported data, but I can't find a way to use it.

For example, let's consider an array called

```
datapourrie = RandomInteger[99, {100000, 2, 5}]
```

First, I export it in simple ASCII format, for the purpose of comparison:

```
Export["expl.dat", datapourrie]
```

`expl.dat` is correctly written, with a size of 4.1 MB.

Now, let's try in HDF5 format:

```
Export["expl.h5", datapourrie, {"Datasets", "mydata"}]
```

The file is correctly written in HDF5 format. It's 5.0 MB (the data + metadata). I tested it with a HDF5 viewer outside of Mathematica: everything's OK.

Now, I'd like to compress it, because one of the main advantages of HDF5 format is that it can be used as a binary (compressed) file format.
From the Mathematica 9 manual, I read:

> `"DataEncoding"` can be none, `"GZIP"` or `"SZIP"`

My problem is that I can't find a way to use this DataEncoding! I would expect the correct sentence to be:

```
 Export["explgzip.h5", datapourrie, {"Datasets", "mydata"}, "DataEncoding" -> "GZIP"]
```

but it produces exactly the same file as without the `"DataEncoding"` tag.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Datasets" seems to be an import setting, not an export setting.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries "Datasets" is an export and import setting as it gives a name to a datasubset. Thus, you can Import a given subset only when you know their dataset name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The documentation is misleading here. On one hand, the only export option is `"Append"` which can be found under the **Options** tab. On the other hand, the general documentation reads

> [image]

I really wonder, why it is necessary to put *Import only* behind an option value when `"DataEncoding"` isn't an export option at all.

Anyway, I have the same behaviour in MacOSX as you have: No data compression. Although, using

```
ExportString[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, "HDF5", "DataEncoding" -> "GZIP"]
```

and changing `"GZIP"` to `None` changes something in the output, but it does not compress the array.

### Partial solution

One possible solution is to gzip the "HDF5" files. This seems to be recognised by *Mathematica* automatically. So either you manually gzip the files, or you use something along these lines to do everything in *Mathematica*

```
Export["matrix.h5.gz", ExportString[datapourrie, "HDF5"], "GZIP"]
```

For your test data this runs in no time, everything else needs probably a benchmarking and tweaking. To re-import your data you can simply do

```
Import["matrix.h5.gz", {"HDF5", "Datasets", "/Dataset1"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for this partial solution.
But DataEncoding is not an import-only setting. Datasets neither.
See for instance this Mathematica manual example:
`Export["m1.h5", {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {"Datasets", "m1"}]`

Comment: `"Datasets"` is not an option, but an element specifier. When you look on other export help pages like [the one of GIF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/GIF.html), you see, that under **Options** you find which option can be used for in- and which for export. But honestly, I find the situation here very weird too.

Answer (score 8):

One workaround is to compress the HDF5 file *after* it has been exported from Mathematica, using [the HDF5 command line tools](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/#h5dist).

Note: on OS X the command line tools can be easily installed using MacPorts using `port install h5utils`.

The command to recompress the data is

```
h5repack -v -f GZIP=1 infile.h5 outfile.h5
```

This can indeed achieve a significant reduction in size.

For convenience you might want to invoke this from within Mathematica using [`Run`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Run.html).

Comment: I sent a support request asking about how to use `"DataEncoding"` properly, because I need this too.  I'll report back when I receive a reply.

Comment: Thanks for this partial solution. I am still interested in finding a solution, so your report is welcome.

Comment: @max The reply I received says that while the correct syntax should be `Export["newtesthdf5.h5", data, {"GZIP", "DataEncoding"}]`, this produces a file that's not readable by HDFView so a bug report has been filed.  I'll re-tag it as a bug based on this.

Comment: Is it just me or is the "correct syntax" strange?

Comment: Any updates on the bug report? yashar asked a question about HDF5 encoding, and then I found this question, and was wondering if the issue has been resolved. Also, what's the correct syntax for specifying both compression (say, "GZIP") and a data format (say, "Real32")? I tried the analogous `Export["randmat.h5", 
 RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000, 1000}], {"GZIP", 
  "DataEncoding"}, {"Real32", "DataFormat"}]` but just got error messages.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus They said that a bug report has been created, but I don't have a workaround.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any updates on this? I can't seem to get it to write out a `Real32` file.

Answer (score 6):

In version 7 halirutan's export method does not produce a file that is recognized by `Import`.

However, one can write:

```
Export["matrix2.h5.gz", datapourrie, {"GZIP", "HDF5"}]
```

And then:

```
d2 = Import["matrix2.h5.gz", {"Datasets", "/Dataset1"}];

datapourrie == d2
```

> True

Comment: This isn't always a workable solution though.  What I need right now is internal compression for HDF5 files, not just separately compressing the HDF5 file with gzip.  I need to produce a non-zipped HDF5 file that uses internal compression and can be directly read by other programs that support the HDF5 format.  I tagged this as a bug because it seems that Mathematica simply doesn't honour the DataEncoding setting.

Comment: Something is still bothering me here: I suspect we're not reading the docs correctly.  It says that "DataEncoding" is a "meta-information element", not an *option*.  So it should be given as an element.  It's not 100% clear to me how this is done properly but I tried: `Export["~/Desktop/d.h5", {"Datasets" -> {data}, 
"DataEncoding" -> "GZIP"}, "Rules"]` based on the Export documentation and some Export examples for other formats.  This still doesn't produce a compressed file though.

Answer (score 1):

You can see:

https://github.com/scotmartin1234/HDF5Mathematica

The package has the functionality you need for writing at low level. HOWEVER, the high level functions are designed more for reading. The package could be expanded as open source project to develop the writing part with the encoding; the encoding is part of the standard C library that is accessed by the interface in Mathematica. It's straight forward to assemble the low level functions into a more Mathematica-friendly format (i.e., the higher level functions), but it would take a volunteer to do so. My efforts and work have been on developing the reading side of the equation into a Mathematica friendly format.

This is version 2.00 (August 2016) of the package that was originally provided as version 1.00 in July 2011.

Comment: does this work in mac?