# Structured HDF5 Export doesn't create any output

Tags: export, hdf5-format

I tried to use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146859/exporting-structured-data-to-hdf5) example to organize my data, but `ExportStructuredHDF5[file,data]` just doesn't create or override a file in the specified folder...

Minimal Exaple:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
data = <| "group" -> <| "entry" -> 1.0 |> |> ;
file = "/path/to/file.h5"
ExportStructuredHDF5[file,data]
```

doesn't do anything.

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong here?

---

Update:
It seems that Structured HDF5 Export ist not supported in Mathematica 10.0. When running the same code on a 11.2 installation, output files are generated.